# How to test graphql apollo component? How to get complete coverage inside compose()?

Tags: redux, graphql, enzyme, istanbul, react-apollo

I'm having issues getting complete coverage on my apollo components. istanbul is reporting the functions inside compose() are not getting called. These are Redux connect() functions and apollo graph() functions.

```
export default compose (
...
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), // <-- functions not covered
graphql(builderQuery, {
    options: (ownProps) => { // <-- function not covered
...
)(ComponentName);
```

I'm mounting using enzyme, trying to do something similar to the [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/tree/master/examples/create-react-app/src) example.

```
const mounted = shallow(
        <MockedProvider mocks={[
            { request: { query, variables }, result: { data: response.data } }
        ]}>
            <ConnectedComponentName />
        </MockedProvider>
    );
```

The only way I've been able to achieve 100% coverage is if I export all of the functions and call them directly.

Comment: I'm trying to use `createMockStore` from `redux-test-utils` with the react-apollo example. `createMockStore` allows you to test your container against given store and let you trigger your dispatches. The current issue is that the mock store can not work with mount(). And shallow() with dive() somehow drops client from context. Please let me know if you have further information.

Comment: @ChrisKong I don't think shallow mounting is correct anymore. Try doing a full mount if its possible. I've found that the utils aren't very useful, especially when you start needing to test `update` and `updateQueries`.

Answer (score 0):

#### testing composed graphql/redux containers

Try something like this for your setup:

```
// mocks.js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import { ApolloClient } from 'react-apollo'
import { mockNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-test-utils'

export const mockApolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: mockNetworkInterface(),
})

export const createMockStore = configureMockStore()
```

This will set you up to properly test your containers:

```
// container-test.js
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { createMockStore, mockApolloClient } from 'mocks'

beforeEach(() => {
  store = createMockStore(initialState)
  wrapper = mount(
    <ApolloProvider client={mockApolloClient} store={store}>
      <Container />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
})

it('maps state & dispatch to props', () => {
  const props = wrapper.find('SearchResults').props()
  const expected = expect.arrayContaining([
    // These props come from an HOC returning my grapqhql composition
    'selectedListing',
    'selectedPin',
    'pathname',
    'query',
    'bbox',
    'pageNumber',
    'locationSlug',
    'selectListing',
    'updateCriteria',
    'selectPin',
  ])
  const actual = Object.keys(props)
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
})
```

#### testing graphql options

Because the graphql fn has a signature like  `graphql(query, config)`, you can export your config for testing in isolation for more granular coverage.

```
import { config } from '../someQuery/config'

describe('config.options', () => {
  const state = {
    bbox: [],
    locationSlug: 'foo',
    priceRange: 'bar',
    refinements: 'baz',
    userSort: 'buzz',
  }

  const results = {
    points: [
      { propertyName: 'Foo' },
      { propertyName: 'Bar' },
    ],
    properties: [
      { propertyName: 'Foo' },
      { propertyName: 'Bar' },
    ],
  }

  it('maps input to variables', () => {
    const { variables } = config.options(state)
    const expected = { bbox: [], locationSlug: 'foo', priceRange: 'bar', refinements: 'baz', userSort: 'buzz' }
    expect(variables).toEqual(expected)
  })

  it('returns props', () => {
    const response = { data: { loading: false, geo: { results } } }
    const props = config.props(response)
    expect(props.results).toEqual(results.properties)
    expect(props.spotlightPoints).toEqual(results.points)
  })
})
```